# how to remove class show from contentNote and addclass show to txtAreaNote with cick on btn-edit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with the following structure. When I click on "btn-edit", I want to remove the "show" class from "contentNote" and add it to "txtAreaNote"; and to add "hide" to "contentNote" and remove it from "txtAreaNote". My jQuery code does not work correctly; how to fix this?

```js
$('.btn-edit').click(function() {
  var btn = $(this);
  btn.each(function() {
    $(this).find(".contentNote").removeClass('show').addClass("hide");
    $(this).find(".txtAreaNote").removeClass('hide').addClass("show");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cm-1">
  <a href="#" class="btn-edit">edit</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn-delete">delete</a>
  <div class="contentNote show">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtAreaNote hide">
    <textarea rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `btn.each(function` ... makes no sense since `this` is what you clicked on, what do you think it is doing?

Comment: Besides the useless `each`, you need to use `parent()` before `find(".contentNote")`, since these elements are siblings, not children of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find()` searches children of the element you're calling it on. Use `nextAll()` or `siblings()` to find following matches (or any matches, before or after, in the case of `siblings()`).

```js
$('.btn-edit').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var btn = $(this);
  btn.nextAll(".contentNote").removeClass('show').addClass("hide");
  btn.nextAll(".txtAreaNote").removeClass('hide').addClass("show");
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cm-1">
  <a href="#" class="btn-edit">edit</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn-delete">delete</a>
  <div class="contentNote show">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtAreaNote hide">
    <textarea rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your full html structure, but it will be something like :

```
$('.btn-edit').click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".cm-1").find(".contentNote").removeClass('show').addClass("hide");
    $(this).closest(".cm-1").find(".txtAreaNote").removeClass('hide').addClass("show");       
});
```

Go to parent class and then search in between two classes.

Comment: Or better use `$.siblings()` method